# Subscribing for a array of form controls-Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

is there any way to subscribe for a array of form control rather than doing multiple get .In my scenario i'm getting a object as shown in the image
[image]
I want to subscribe  when textfielda,textfieldb and numbera valuechanges only.I tried subscribing for valuechanges of the entire form(working fine) but it is an expensive operation so is there any workaround to acheive this.This field are dynamic so i cant use ngmodel .Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'd still need to get each individual control then add their `valueChanges` to an Array then use `Observable.merge`. Here's an example I made couple of days ago regarding getting valueChanges to specific element in a FormArray, I think you can modify and get what you need: https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarraything

Comment: So , there is no way that come out of box from angular . Can you explain your approach deeper

Comment: Yes. The goal is to get valueChanges on specific/single element of a FormArray. If you subscribe to a FormArray ValueChanges, it will log the whole Array. Because it’s a FormArray, so I can add and remove FormControl dynamically. For that reason, I need to get each control with forEach, then push `control.valueChanges` to an observableArray. At the end, I also push the `formArray.valueChanges` to the observableArray to get the change from the FormArray as well. Then I use `Observable.merge` to merge all those valueChanges then use `distinctUntilChanged` to only get value when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do it's copied from my code and edited.

Every form group in my form array has a dataype:

```
newFormArray.push(this.fb.group({
  datatype: datatype,
  value: value
}));
```

These are values of an api call with a backend connected to the db.

What you do now is:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((item: any) => {
  if(item.array[i].datatype === 'textarea'){ //do something
  switch (item.array[i].datatype) { // or with a switch
        case 'textarea':
          //do textarea
          break;
```

Ofc in the HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="item.datatype === 'textarea'"> // show textarea
```